# Save changes on web using inspect element

Tags: html, css, caching, browser

im using the inspect element menu to modify a little a site (F1.com) because I want to see only some parts of the web.

Now, i want to make that changes persistent (only for my browser, as I cant change the original files)

For example, I have deleted some divs, edited the CSS, and I want that when I refresh the page on the browser, cache files use my changes, making them persistent..

Is there anyway to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to look into [Workspaces](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/setup/setup-workflow?hl=en).